# SQL: Best practice for inserting a record if it doesn't exist

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have an asp.net Gridview that handles insert operations into a SQL database. Records are only permitted to be inserted if they meet a uniqueness criteria, and this constraint is being enforced using unique indexes in SQL server. If the user attempts to insert a record that already exists, an error message is displayed.

I'm wondering what the best practice is for implementing this.

1. Check if the record exists SQL side, using IF EXISTS, and locking hints (updlock, holdlock, etc). Return an error code to ASP.net depending on whether the record was inserted
2. Perform the INSERT operation inside a SQL server try/catch block, relying on the unique index to prevent the insert from occurring if the record exists. Return an error code depending on whether an exception was thrown.
3. Perform the INSERT operation SQL side, but without SQL try/catch. Handle the PK violation exception inside ASP.net instead.

Normally I'd consider using exceptions to handle valid operations to be bad practice - i.e. software should not throw exceptions unless something is broken. However if the unique index on the table in SQL is going to implement the desired constraint, why bother performing a manual check for existence of the record?

Comment: MERGE is not available in the version of SQL I'm using (2005), and I don't want to update the record if it already exists. If the record exists, a notification is displayed to the user

Comment: If you have a index on your contraint keys option 1. is probably the best way to to this without exceptions and fast.

Comment: You could put your IF EXISTS logic in an INSTEAD OF TRIGGER and check for existence and what not.  You could also put your proc that does the IF EXISTS logic and let the INSTEAD OF TRIGGER be the means of invoking it automatically for you.  The benefit is all app logic that try to insert will have this in place for them so you could make the change once and have it globally enforced so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a separate call to check if the record already exists. If yes, show message to user, if no make insert. The reason I would do it this way is because I prefer keeping all the business logic in the application.

If you insist in making just one stored proc call:

I would check before I insert. I would also add an output parameter to the stored proc that returns a message if the insert was unsuccessful. In my application if I see a message in the output parameter, I will display that to the user.